# Flask render_template taking 5+ seconds to run

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to display a page with some data, passing a dictionary through to the jinja template. This takes a ridiculously long time to load, easily 5-10 seconds for a very small dataset. This is what my Python looks like

```
@app.route("/request") 
def request_page(): 
    category_dict = CONFIG.get_categories() 
    return render_template('request.html', category_dict=category_dict)
```

And this is what my HTML looks like

```
   {% extends "layout.html" %}
   {% block title %}Categories{% endblock %}
   {% block content %}
        <h1 class="display-4">Category List</h1>
           <form method='post' action='/result' onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
             <div class="form-group">
                 {% for category, list in category_dict.items() %}
                   <div class="card">
                     <div class="card-header">
                      <a class="text-dark" data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{loop.index}}">
                        {{category}}
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="{{loop.index}}" class="collapse">
                    <div class="card-body text-small">
                      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                         {% for project in list %}
                          <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="form-check">
                              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="{{project}}" id="{{project}}">
                              <label class="form-check-label" for="{{project}}">
                                      {{project}}
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
              <br>
              <h5>Reason for group access</h5>
              <textarea rows="4" cols="60" name="reasons">
              </textarea>
              <br>
            <button class='btn btn-primary' name='Submit'>Submit</button>
          </form>
 {% endblock %}
```

So as an overview, its a nested for loop where the outer loop iterates through the key value pairs of the dictionary and the inner loop iterates through the values, which are lists of strings. The dictionary that I'm passing through isn't very big, ~5 keys and maybe ~5 items in each list. Doing some tests also revealed that the slowdown is definitely with this chunk of code in the HTML, not in the layout.html or anything.

Comment: Show the code for `get_categories`.

Comment: some comments: 1) don't use `list` for a variable name. 2) Does it get any faster if you use `category_dict.iteritems()` ?

Comment: @JacobIRR 1) Noted. 2) iteritems doesn't exist in Python 3 so I can't use it unfortunately.